# NPM commands not working, exits with error code 127 on installing anything

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm making an express app on my windows machine and everything was working fine until yesterday.
But today no npm command of mine is working.
`npm install` results in the following:
[image]

`npm start` results in:
[image]

Even if I run `node server.js`, it results in:
[image]

My package.json is as follows:

```
  "name": "examhub",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "<confidential>"
  },
  "author": "<confidential>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "<confidential>"
  },
  "homepage": "<confidential>",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-flash-messages": "^0.1.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "filepond": "^4.30.4",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.1",
    "node": "^18.10.0",
    "passport": "^0.5.3",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

I have installed and uninstalled node multiple times now and am clueless as to why this is happening.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your PATH does not include the location of the node executable.

`You can likely run node as "/usr/local/bin/node".`

You can add that location to your path by running the following command to add a single line to your bashrc file:

`echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc source $HOME/.bashrc`

Also check if node is specified in path in `environment variables`

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.
Reason being, I can run any other .js file using "node file.js". The problem only arises when I'm trying to start my server or install any npm package. Either way, I included node to system variables and restarted the system. The problem still persists.